# How to create an array filled any number of empty arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Per the title, I'm trying to create an array that is filled with any number of empty arrays in JavaScript.

As an example, let's say I wanted to create an array filled with 9 empty arrays. I could do something like this, which works, but looks quite bad:

```
let myArray = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
```

I tried using the fill method, but if I push to any of the empty arrays, the other arrays get filled as well:

```
let myArray = Array(9).fill([]);

myArray[0].push(1);
// Output = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]];
```

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a nice one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill it with [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each item:

```js
let myArray = Array(9).fill().map(e => [])
myArray[0].push(1);

console.log(myArray)
```